# How to add the IP address to the config file in Windows host?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that's hosted as a Windows service.
The windows service is installed using InstallUtil.

After the installation I have to manually specify the base address to be used by the endpoint.

Can I get the IP address dynamically and update the config file during installation?

I know this is not recommended but the customer wants the service to run out of the box with minimal or no configuration done on his part.

Regards.

Comment: Maybe, configure wcf service in code ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can pass parameter to install util command line but for that you need to change the installer class of windows service little bit. [Check out this link for how to do it](http://blog.dotnetstep.in/2009/06/passing-parameter-to-installutil.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow these steps for the solution :

step1 : You need to run Notepad as an administrator when you edit it because your hosts file is a system file. Doing this is quite easy. Find Notepad in your start menu (usually in the accessories), right click on in, and then click "Run as administrator".
step2 :Before you can edit your hosts file, you need to find it. Not all versions of Windows store it in the same place, but in our experience it's usually located in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts Other possible locations include:

```
Windows 95/98/Me c:\windows\hosts 
Windows NT/2000/XP Pro c:\winnt\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
Windows XP Home/Vista/Windows 7 c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

step3 :    In Notepad click "File" and then "Open.."
    Find the drop down next to "File name". It by default says "Text Documents (*.txt). Change this to "All Files(*.*)"
    Navigate to the folder where your hosts file is located
    Double Click hosts to open it
step4:  We recommend that you back up the host file before making any modifications to it. To do this:

```
In Notepad click "File" and then "Save As..."
For the "File name:" value, enter something different, such as hosts_backup_2011.05.31
Click "Save"
```